# react-share data not showing

Tags: next.js, react-share

I am working on adding social sharing buttons using Next.js 13 and react-share. Seems pretty simple however regardless of what I do it's not working. When clicking the TwitterShareButton below the only things that show are the url and title within TwitterShareButton aka [www.coolsite.com](http://www.coolsite.com). What am I doing wrong?

```
    import { TwitterShareButton } from "react-share";
    import Head from "next/head";
    
    <Head>
      <title>Cool Title</title>
      <meta name="description" content="Cool Description" />
      <meta property="og:image" content="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png" />
      <meta property="og:title" content="Cool Title" />
      <meta property="og:description" content="Cool Description" />
    
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="Cool" />
      <meta name="twitter:site" content="Cool" />
      <meta name="twitter:title" content="Cool Title" />
      <meta name="twitter:description" content="Cool Description" />
      <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png" />
    </Head>;
    
    export default function Share() {
      return (
        <div>
          <TwitterShareButton
            url="https://www.coolsite.com"
            title="Now that site is cool."
          >
            Share on Twitter
          </TwitterShareButton>
        </div>
      );
    }
```